# Elastic search array of objects nested range aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to make range aggregation on the following data set:

```
{
    "ProductType": 1,
                    "ProductDefinition": "fc588f8e-14f2-4871-891f-c73a4e3d17ca",
                    "ParentProduct": null,
                    "Sku": "074617",
                    "VariantSku": null,
                    "Name": "Paraboot Avoriaz/Jannu Marron Brut Marron Brown Hiking Boot Shoes",
                    "AllowOrdering": true,
                    "Rating": null,
                    "ThumbnailImageUrl": "/media/1106/074617.jpg",
                    "PrimaryImageUrl": "/media/1106/074617.jpg",
                    "Categories": [
                        "399d7b20-18cc-46c0-b63e-79eadb9390c7"
                    ],
                    "RelatedProducts": [],
                    "Variants": [
                        "84a7ff9f-edf0-4aab-87f9-ba4efd44db74",
                        "e2eb2c50-6abc-4fbe-8fc8-89e6644b23ef",
                        "a7e16ccc-c14f-42f5-afb2-9b7d9aefbc5c"
                    ],
                    "PriceGroups": [
                        "86182755-519f-4e05-96ef-5f93a59bbaec"
                    ],
                    "DisplayName": "Paraboot Avoriaz/Jannu Marron Brut Marron Brown Hiking Boot Shoes",
                    "ShortDescription": "",
                    "LongDescription": "<ul><li>Paraboot Avoriaz Mountaineering Boots</li><li>Marron Brut Marron (Brown)</li><li>Full leather inners and uppers</li><li>Norwegien Welted Commando Sole</li><li>Hand made in France</li><li>Style number : 074617</li></ul><p>As featured on <a href=\"http://www.pritchards.co.uk/shoes-trainers-11/paraboot-avoriaz-jannu-marron-brut-brown-20879.htm\">Pritchards.co.uk</a></p>",
                    "UnitPrices": {
                        "EUR 15 pct": 343.85
                    },
                    "Taxes": {
                        "EUR 15 pct": 51.5775
                    },
                    "PricesInclTax": {
                        "EUR 15 pct": 395.4275
                    },
                    "Slug": "paraboot-avoriazjannu-marron-brut-marron-brown-hiking-boot-shoes",
                    "VariantsProperties": [
                        {
                            "Key": "ShoeSize",
                            "Value": "8"
                        },
                        {
                            "Key": "ShoeSize",
                            "Value": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "Key": "ShoeSize",
                            "Value": "6"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Guid": "0d4f6899-c66a-4416-8f5d-26822c3b57ae",
                    "Id": 178,
                    "ShowOnHomepage": true
                }
```

I'm aggregating on VariantsProperties which have the following mapping

```
"VariantsProperties": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "Key": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "Value": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Terms aggregations are working fine with following code:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "Nest": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "VariantsProperties"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "fieldIds": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "VariantsProperties.Key"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "values": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "VariantsProperties.Value"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However when I try to do a range aggregation to get shoes in size between 8 - 12 such as:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "Nest": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "VariantsProperties"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "fieldIds": {
                    "range": {
                        "field": "VariantsProperties.Value",
                        "ranges": [ { "from": 8, "to": 12 }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Field [VariantsProperties.Value] of type [keyword] is not supported for aggregation [range]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "product-avenueproductindexdefinition-24476f82-en-us",
                "node": "ejgN4XecT1SUfgrhzP8uZg",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                    "reason": "Field [VariantsProperties.Value] of type [keyword] is not supported for aggregation [range]"
                }
            }
        ],
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Field [VariantsProperties.Value] of type [keyword] is not supported for aggregation [range]",
            "caused_by": {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Field [VariantsProperties.Value] of type [keyword] is not supported for aggregation [range]"
            }
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Is there a way to "transform" the terms aggregation into a range aggregation, without the need of changing the schema? I know I could build the ranges myself by extracting the data from the terms aggregation and building the ranges out of it, however, I would prefer a solution within the elastic itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this:

Option A: Use a script instead of a field. This option will work without having to reindex your data, but depending on your volume of data, the performance might suffer.

```
POST test/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "Nest": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "VariantsProperties"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "fieldIds": {
          "range": {
            "script": "Integer.parseInt(doc['VariantsProperties.Value'].value)",
            "ranges": [
              {
                "from": 8,
                "to": 12
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Option B: Add an `integer` [sub-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html#_multi_fields) in your mapping.

```
PUT my-index/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "VariantsProperties": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "Key": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "Value": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "numeric": {
              "type": "integer",
              "ignore_malformed": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Once your mapping is modified, you can run `_update_by_query` on your index in order to reindex the `VariantsProperties.Value` data

```
PUT my-index/_update_by_query
```

Finally, when this last command is done, you can run the `range` aggregation on the `VariantsProperties.Value.numeric` field.

Also note that this second but will be more performant on the long term.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer, I really like the option B, however, I'm not sure what would the "numeric" field contain? Would it contain the actual values of the shoe sizes? Something like "VariantsProperties": [{"Key": "ShoeSize","Value": {"numeric": 8}} ?

Comment: You'll have a new field available for your queries and aggregations which is called `VariantsProperties.Value.numeric`, but you don't have to change anything in the way you index the data. You can simply modify the mapping using PUT and then call `_update_by_query` on your index. I've updated my answer to show you how to do it.

Comment: Alright, thanks it works, I've marked the your answer as accepted, thank you, one more question, would it be possible to do this conditionally? I mean what if some of the variants properties are not parsable into integers, like plain strings? Would that need a separate field or can they be mixed and then parsed afterwards?

Comment: Thanks again, everything works. Is this pattern/approach called somehow so I could read up on it? Since I'd like to know what the `Numeric` is doing exactly and how is it possible it works although it doesn't have a value.

Comment: Yes, sure, it's called [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html#_multi_fields) and it allows you to provide the value only once and index it in different ways for different needs.