# How to run wildcard queries for long types?

Tags: elasticsearch

I just run a simple wildcard query on my elasticsearch server.

My query is;

```
GET calls-*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "default_field": "foo.number",
                  "query": "*16922*"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The error response looks like this;

```
Can only use wildcard queries on keyword, text, and wildcard fields - not on [foo.number] which is of type [long]
```

when I check the index info I saw the `number` type is `long`. If I switch to `text` from `long` everything worked as expected. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67949362/14373656) says exact same thing.

```
"number": {
  "type": "long",
  "ignore_malformed": false,
  "coerce": true
},
```

But I can't change the number type because the code will ship to the prod server and I can't modify any prod elastic index.

So how can I run my wildcard queries without any errors? If the only way is the modifying the index (switch `text` from the `long`), can I replace wildcard queries with another method?

Comment: You can also keep the `long` field but [create a subfield of type text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65610005/4604579) and use it in your query

Comment: Thanks, @Val is this the best way to use wildcard search to find a result that something contains a specific word? I mean can we replace something that can support long data types

Comment: It's not the best way but you said you "can't change the number type because the code will ship to the prod server", so it's a viable alternative. Another alternative is to use ngrams, but depending on the data volume, it might induce a big performance hit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You cannot perform wildcard search directly on the numeric data type fields***

If you want to perform a wildcard search on long-type fields then 1 way is to update your index mapping, reindex the data, and then use the wildcard search.

While updating the index mapping, you can keep the type of `foo.number` field as `long`, and add one sub-field to it of type `text`, using [Update Mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) as shown below :

**Step 1: Update Mapping**

```
PUT /_mapping
{
    "properties": {
        "foo": {
            "properties": {
                "number": {
                    "type": "long",
                    "fields": {
                        "key": {
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Reindex the data**

**Step 3: Search Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "default_field": "foo.number.key",
                  "query": "*123*"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

After hitting the above search and following Step 1 and Step 2, you will get your desired result.

Comment: Thanks, @ESCoder, is this the best way to use wildcard search to find a result that something contains a specific word?

Comment: @heymynameisfoo AFAIK it's not directly possible to use wildcard search on numeric data types. So, if you want to do a wildcard search, the optimal way is to convert your numeric data type to string, and then perform a search on it.